# Magento Installer Error

Tags: magento

I am trying to install magento in media temple hosting account.While installing i am getting the error

```
Error in file: "app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/sql/dataflow_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.7.3-0.7.4.php" - SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db128510_main.dataflow_batch' doesn't exist

Trace:
#0 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(390): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(289): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '0.7.3', '0.7.4')
#2 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(233): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('0.7.3', '0.7.4')
#3 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(161): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(399): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(329): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /app/Mage.php(627): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

If i manually create the table and reinstall,installer outputs another table doesn't exists.I also ran magento system requirement checking script and found no issue.Its fresh install and not any upgrades.Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues while trying to upgrade magento versions. Please try adding the following line to the top of that setup script:

```
$this->getConnection()->disallowDdlCache();
```

Also I don't think it matters much, but for good measure try to clear the DDL cache too:

```
$this->getConnection()->resetDdlCache();
```

It's a long shot, but it may work in your case.

Edit in response to your comment:

Magento caches DDL statements under the covers. Which means it will be able to execute some SQL statements a little bit faster. But sometimes this causes problems during updates. I think it has something to do with foreign keys and invalidated cache data.